# MongoDB findOneAndReplace log if added as new document or replaced

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm using mongo's [findOneAndReplace()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndReplace/%20findOneAndReplace) with `upsert = true` and `returnNewDocument = true`

as basically a way to not insert duplicate. But I want to get the `_id` of the new inserted document (or the old existing document) to be passed to a background processing task.

BUT I also want to log if the document was Added-As-New or if a Replacement took place.

I can't see any way to use `findOneAndReplace()` with these parameters and answer that question.

The only think I can think of is to find, and insert in two different requests which seems a bit counter-productive.

ps. I'm actually using pymongo's `find_one_and_replace()` but it seems identical to the JS mongo function.

EDIT: edited for clarification.

Comment: with return new document are you not getting the replaced document ? You should be able to get the _id from the replaced document. May be I am not understanding the question ?

Comment: I need to LOG whether the document was Added-as-new or if a Replacement occured. I'm using findOneAndReplace because my adding script becomes idempotetent but I'm still curious about new things that are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not possible to use replace_one function ? In java I am able to use repalceOne which returns UpdateResult. That has method for finding if documented updated or not. I see repalce_one in pymongo and it should behave same. Here is doc [PyMongo Doc](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) Look for replace_one

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm going to implement it for now (in python):

```
import pymongo

def find_one_and_replace_log(collection, find_query,
                             document_data,
                             log={}):
    ''' behaves like find_one_or_replace(upsert=True,
    return_document=pymongo.ReturnDocument.AFTER)
    '''
    is_new = False
    document = collection.find_one(find_query)
    if not document:
        # document didn't exist
        # log as NEW
        is_new = True
    new_or_replaced_document = collection.find_one_and_replace(
        find_query,
        document_data,
        upsert=True,
        return_document=pymongo.ReturnDocument.AFTER
    )
    log['new_document'] = is_new
    return new_or_replaced_document
```